# Likelihood proportional to several functions

Tags: probability, bayesian, density-estimation

Hi I have some probability density functions, $f_1$, $f_2$,... etc and know they are proportional to the following expressions:

- $f_1(X) \propto \frac{\frac{1}{p}^X}{(1-p)^X}$
- $f_2(X) \propto \frac{1}{(1-p)^X(1/p)^X}$
- $f_3(X) \propto (\frac{1}{p})^X(1-p)^X$
- $f_4(X) \propto p^X(1-p)^X$
- $f_5(X) \propto \frac{1}{(1-p)^Xp^X}$

Where $X \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ and $p \in [0,1]$. Does anyone know which of the above, if any, correspond to known distributions and if so which?

Comment: Contingent on the possible values of $X$ (which you haven't specified), every one of these is the same, because they are all of the form $f_i(x)=\exp(\kappa \log(x))$ for some constant $\kappa.$ Thus, $\log(X)$ has a distribution closely related to the Exponential (*aka* Gamma$(1)$) distribution.  However, that might be misleading, because the form in which you write your expressions suggests the values of $X$ might be limited to a finite range of integers: it is important that you specify what the possible values might be.

Comment: Apologies yes that was bad form of me. I have now added the values.

Comment: Thank you.  Where it makes sense, these are all [geometric distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  It makes no sense in the cases where the base is $1$ or greater; for instance, $ f_5$ *never* defines a distribution.  Because of this, one is left wondering whether you are asking a question that is meaningful to you or whether it reflects some analytical error that was committed previously.

Comment: Aren't f5 and f1 exactly the same?